# How to create a function app for Iothub builtin endpoint trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I have a iothub with the built-in-endpoint set. In the message routing of the IotHub, I've selected Built-in-endpoint>events to route device telemetry.

Now, I am wondering how can I trigger the Azure function app when this built-in-endpoint receives the event.

Would the Function App be EventHub Triggered or would it be IotHub Triggered? If eventHub triggered, what would be the connection and eventhub name I'd set in the Run method of the Function App?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IotHUB has an eventhub running under its hood which is why it can get confusing. You can select iothub trigger. Then create a new Eventhub connection and select IOThub. Your iothub should then appear in the dropdown.

You can follow [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Paw_twmmodY) video from 19:00.